# I uninstalled/deleted a system privileged app (from /system/priv-app) How can I reinstall it?

Tags: root-access, boot-loop, system-apps

I uninstalled the DocumentsUI only to know it wasn't "just" a files manager. My `/system/priv-app/DocumentsUI` is empty. Putting any 3rd party DocumentsUI.apk in it results in bootloop. I have a custom rom (Aosp extended).

Flashing the `/system` again would fix the problem I think. Just want to make sure if this will make the condition worse or am I going alright?

Comment: Extract the file from ROM's zip file and put in proper place with proper permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I did it was a little different.. I made a full twrp backup. Wiped everyhing. Flashed the stock rom. Copied the `DocumentsUI.apk` from twrp. Wiped again. Restored the backup. Placed the copied apk into `/system/priv-app/DocumentsUI`. Everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

This answer was before the edit but holds

Flashing `/Data` would result in:

- Losing your user data.
- Worse, it's not going to solve your problem.

**Solutions**

- Dirty flash the ROM ( flash `/system` without wiping `/Data`)
- As suggested by Irfan in [comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231625/i-deleted-the-documentsui-by-mistake-where-can-i-get-it#comment304531_231625),
  Extract the file from ROM's zip file and put in proper place with proper permissions.

Second option requires a good understanding of Android. For me, dirty flashing would be fastest and simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to root for this

Install any root browser (x-plorer , cx file manager etc.

open /system/priv-app/DocumentsUIGoogle

3.copy all apk files to any internel storage folder

Install all these apk files at once using any split apk installer ( Recommended -com.smartpack.packagemanager )
download link - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartpack.packagemanager

5.Reboot

Note :- if you are unable to find these apk files then use attached files
vvvvv
https://mega.nz/folder/R1UxBbYJ#BD6jRT52rADTGA09x6EBcA

Note 2 => if you don't have any DocumentsUIGoogle folder then create one and put all apk files into it then install all these apks using package manager.